# "Dadurch, dass"-Konstruktionen

Tags: sentence-structure

> Dadurch, dass Latein in der Medizin eine wichtige Rolle spielt, ist es
>   nicht vom Aussterben bedroht.

Does the construction: "dadurch, dass" indicate causality? Or does it indicate the means of action in the sentence (like "indem")?

Comment: *Means of action* would indicate *some action* by the subject, which isn't present - The Latin language is pretty passive nowadays and doesn't do anything actively. ;)

Comment: some actions are still present in Medicine and in some Churches :-)

Comment: It tends to be spoken there - You see this is passive?

Comment: no at all! though it is not spoken in Medicine .... just some definitions and terms ... but eventually not spoken!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I would say it is causality. "Because Latin has a big role in medicine it is not going down" (not completely correct translation). The "dadurch, dass" tells us that the situation is shown after it (latin has a big role in medicine) which then goes over to the thing that follows out of this situation.